# What do these operators mean in Elixir? ~>>, <<~

Tags: operators, elixir

What do these operators mean in Elixir? `~>>, <<~`

They are listed here http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/basic-operators.html

I get the following error:

```
iex(28)> b=1
1
iex(29)> b~>>1
** (CompileError) iex:29: undefined function ~>>/2
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are some operators that currently have no meaning, but you can use them in macros you define or just define them as functions. For example:

```elixir
defmodule Operators do
  def a ~>> b do
    a + b
  end
end

defmodule Test do
  def test do
    import Operators

    1 ~>> 2
  end
end

IO.inspect(Test.test) # => 3
```

The general idea is that Elixir wants to avoid operator proliferation (think libraries that define dozens of new operators) so when defining your macros you need to use the ones that are already there.